# Rocketchip (riscv) acclerator performance evaluation

Tags: riscv, chisel, rocket-chip

I have implemented accelerator on Rocket chip generator using Rocc. How to compute the performance of accelerator and compare with C implementation. I have written C implementation and computing the cycles as "Cycle = End - Begin". Where end and begin are calling read_csr(mcycle). I use it by reading dhrystone.h in RISCV-test github. Is this right way to calculate the cycles ?

I am thinking of using this technique for both accelerator and C implementation.
Can i use CSR  for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great use of the RISC-V Hardware Performance Monitors (HPMs). If you are running your benchmark in machine mode, you can read `mcycle` to measure the passage on cycles. If you are running in user mode, you have instructions like `rdcycle` to give you user-level access to the cycle counter.